# Append float to list with for loop in python

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to add a list of monthly temperatures into a big list that will contain 24 months of temperatures. The problem is that they are given in floats, but to append items, they must be integers.

```
temperatures = []
np.array(temperatures, dtype = np.float32)
```

(after my first month, I append my values to the big list temperatures and empty TEMP1 for the next month)

```
for item in TEMP1:    
      np.insert(temperatures, TEMP1[item])
```

the message of error is :

```
File "/home/piscopo/Bureau/EC/Alert_extraction.py", line 87, in <module>
np.insert(temperatures, TEMP1[item])

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not numpy.float32
```

Thank you

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding the error. You're *indexing* TEMP1 with the value you're trying to insert, for some reason.

Comment: Also I have the same problem, but instead of floats, it's will datetime64. I hope that with this answer, I will be able to solve both of my problems.

Comment: Why are you using `np.array()` but ignoring the return value? Did you read the `np.insert()` documentation, you are getting the arguments mixed up here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to save your nparray in a variable and then you can add your TEMP1 monthly temperatures all at once with the method append() like this :

```
import numpy as np

TEMP1 = [22.4, 14.4, 12.3]
temperatures = []
floatTemperatures = np.array(temperatures, dtype = np.float32)

floatTemperatures = np.append(floatTemperatures, TEMP1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it also works with datetime64. Very greatful.